# Accessing form attributes in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to get django's generic FormView function to work. But can't figure out what's teh problem.

This is my form:

```
class JobCreateForm(forms.Form):
title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def save(self, user):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    company = user.get_profile().get_company()

    # create job
    job = Job(title=data.title, description=data.description, company=company, user=user)
    job.save()
```

This is my view:

```
class JobCreate(FormView):

form_class = JobCreateForm
template_name = "jobs/create.html"

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save(self.request.user)
    return super(JobCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

and this is my template:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

When I try to do form.save(...), I get an error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'title'`.
What's wrong there?

Comment: You should be using a ModelForm in any case. It both creates the fields and defines a save method for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `dict.title` to `dict['title']`

Answer (score 2):

This is because self.cleaned_data is not an object but a dictionary. Eg. you can't access it by .(dot) notation.

You have to select it from dict like:

```
title = data['title']
```

or better way:

```
title = data.get('title',None)
```

which will try to obtain the title from dictionary and if it doesn't succeed, it will set the **None** to the title.